# How do I animate a clicked link before leaving page?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, css-transitions

Here's what I want to achieve:

1. When an HTML link is clicked, I want to animate it before leaving the page
2. If the link is opened in a new window/tab, the animation should not take place

How on earth do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use javascript

```
$(function(){
  $(".btn").bind("click",function(){
    $(this).animate({'left': '100px'}, 100, function(){
    window.location.href = index.html
  })
 })
})
```

But you'll have to stop the default action if your button is a link.

Comment: I'm not sure about the second part

Comment: No buttons, just links. Playing the animation at the link's click event isn't really an option, because the click event doesn't know whether I'm opening the link in the same window (animation should play) or in a new window (animation should NOT play).

Comment: You need to `return false` or call `preventDefault` in click event.

Comment: Yeah you'll need to prevent the default and make the window.location.href the link you want to go to.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to capture the click event, prevent the default action, do the animation, then load the new page.

If using jquery (Available as [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Vhgq/1/)):

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).animate({
    //whatever
  }, function() {
    location.href = $(this).attr("href");
  });
});
```

**Update**: [Here's the new](http://jsfiddle.net/JonAbrams/3Vhgq/2/) jsfiddle that accounts for the situation mentioned in the comments, go there for the updated code. The trick is to look for the keypress of ctrl or command, and abort the newly defined animated click handler if either key is pressed.

Note: The window needs focus before it can detect a keypress, in jsfiddle, that means the frame needs focus before it'll work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't think this satisfies requirement #2. If the user opens the link's context menu and selects "Open in new window", the link is opened in a new window without playing the animation, which is as it should be. But if the user holds down CRTL/CMD and clicks the link, your proposed method will play the animation and open the link in the same window.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle, it should handle the situation you mentioned now. I'm on a mac so I couldn't test "ctrl" but it should work (it works with Command).